# How to create a live scorer app for Android?

Tags: android, live

I am developing an android app where I will provide a button on which, when ever the user clicks, they will get the live score updates of the Soccer game.

Are there any tutorials for that or, any Open-source code available for that

I am trying to achieve some what like the image given below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You would somehow have to retrieve the current score from a server.

Answer (score 0):

Your required tasks is pretty straight forward. I suggest you use the android developers site to learn the basics and tool stack involved in android programming. Early in this process you will come across the 'Views' tutorial which outlines about half of what you need to do (display the scores in a pretty format).

I suggest you get this part of it running first (just a pretty display with test scores on it), after that creating the network request and getting the data from the server should a fairly easy path using Android's or apache HTTP classes.

Answer (score 0):

You would basically need a site which can provide you the live data in an xml format, for instance. There are sites which provide this. Of course, they won't provide it for free. May be you would get it free for some smaller league for you to test. 
You can simply read the xml, using xml serialization or maybe XmlDocument if you use c# as a language for scripting.

I did a simple google search, and I found this article by www.thegamecontriver.com, they use unity to create a Live Standing App. Maybe you will find this useful. Of course, it is not difficult to use the same method to do it for Live Scores.

You can find the link for the post here
[Live Standings App Tutorial](http://www.thegamecontriver.com/2014/12/how-to-make-live-football-soccer-score.html)